# Составить UI интерфейс Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

есть табы и связанный фрагмент, как сделать интерфейс который изображен ниже? 
Для C-элементов можно сделать через recyclerview, так как они будут с бесконечной прокруткой. Вопрос как добавить элементы **A и B**, количество сообщений для элементов "A" будет ровно 7, а для "B" элементов кол-во элементов будет 10 шт (слайдер с пролистыванием с права на лево).

[image: схема как должно быть]
[image: пустой интерфейс]

Comment: Да тут вроде все можно на RecyclerView сделать. Только в A нужно выше RecyclerView добавить ImageView и TextView

Comment: спасибо за направление, недавно начал заниматься разработкой на android особо не судите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В трех случаях следует использовать - `RecyclerView`

Для **A** случая в качестве `layoutManager` вам нужен `GridLayoutManager`

Для **B** случая в качестве `layoutManager` вам нужен `LinearLayoutManager` и `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Для **C** случая в качестве `layoutManager` вам нужен  `LinearLayoutManager`  и `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Здравствуйте, получается в одном фрагменте необходимо использовать несколько RecyclerView?

Comment: @Alisher-Ergashev Да.